# Merging Overlapping Rectangle in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, rectangles, object-detection

I'm using OpenCV 3.0. I've made a car detection program and I keep running into the problem of overlapping bounding boxes:

[image]

Is there a way to merge overlapping bounding boxes as described on the images below?
I've used `rectangle(frame, Point(x1, y1), Point(x2, y2), Scalar(255,255,255));` to draw those bounding boxes. I've searched for answer from similiar threads but I can't find them helpful. I'd like to form a single outer bounding rectangle after merging those bounding boxes.

Comment: a single outer bounding rectangle please.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21770696/5294258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

Seems as if you are displaying each contour you are getting. You don't have to do that. Follow the algorithm and code given below.

### Algorithm

In this case what you can do is iterate through each contour that you detect and select the biggest **boundingRect**. You don't have to display each contour you detect.

Here is a code that you can use.

### Code

```
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ) // iterate through each contour. 
      {
       double a=contourArea( contours[i],false);  //  Find the area of contour
       if(a>largest_area){
       largest_area=a;
       largest_contour_index=i;                //Store the index of largest contour
       bounding_rect=boundingRect(contours[i]); // Find the bounding rectangle for biggest contour
       }

      }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As I've mentioned in a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54598750/6411572), this is a problem best solved by Non Maximum Suppression.

Although your code is in C++, have a look at [this pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/) article (python) to get an idea on how this works.

I've translated this code from python to C++,.

```
struct detection_box
{
    cv::Rect box;               /*!< Bounding box */
    double svm_val;             /*!< SVM response at that detection*/
    cv::Size res_of_detection;  /*!< Image resolution at which the detection occurred */
};

/*!
\brief Applies the Non Maximum Suppression algorithm on the detections to find the detections that do not overlap

The svm response is used to sort the detections. Translated from http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/

\param boxes list of detections that are the input for the NMS algorithm
\param overlap_threshold the area threshold for the overlap between detections boxes. boxes that have overlapping area above threshold are discarded


\returns list of final detections that are no longer overlapping
*/
std::vector<detection_box> nonMaximumSuppression(std::vector<detection_box> boxes, float overlap_threshold)
{
    std::vector<detection_box> res;
    std::vector<float> areas;

    //if there are no boxes, return empty 
    if (boxes.size() == 0)
        return res;

    for (int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++)
        areas.push_back(boxes[i].box.area());

    std::vector<int> idxs = argsort(boxes);     

    std::vector<int> pick;          //indices of final detection boxes

    while (idxs.size() > 0)         //while indices still left to analyze
    {
        int last = idxs.size() - 1; //last element in the list. that is, detection with highest SVM response
        int i = idxs[last];
        pick.push_back(i);          //add highest SVM response to the list of final detections

        std::vector<int> suppress;
        suppress.push_back(last);

        for (int pos = 0; pos < last; pos++)        //for every other element in the list
        {
            int j = idxs[pos];

            //find overlapping area between boxes
            int xx1 = max(boxes[i].box.x, boxes[j].box.x);          //get max top-left corners
            int yy1 = max(boxes[i].box.y, boxes[j].box.y);          //get max top-left corners
            int xx2 = min(boxes[i].box.br().x, boxes[j].box.br().x);    //get min bottom-right corners
            int yy2 = min(boxes[i].box.br().y, boxes[j].box.br().y);    //get min bottom-right corners

            int w = max(0, xx2 - xx1 + 1);      //width
            int h = max(0, yy2 - yy1 + 1);      //height

            float overlap = float(w * h) / areas[j];    

            if (overlap > overlap_threshold)        //if the boxes overlap too much, add it to the discard pile
                suppress.push_back(pos);
        }

        for (int p = 0; p < suppress.size(); p++)   //for graceful deletion
        {
            idxs[suppress[p]] = -1;
        }

        for (int p = 0; p < idxs.size();)
        {
            if (idxs[p] == -1)
                idxs.erase(idxs.begin() + p);
            else
                p++;
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pick.size(); i++)       //extract final detections frm input array
        res.push_back(boxes[pick[i]]);

    return res;

}
```